# Data Being Lost on Model Error in OnPost Method in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I want to show the email of a user in a label and Full name inside a form (where user can only change the full name not the email)

But in OnPost method, in a model error (ie, when the full name is empty) the email data is load when the same page loads.

Below is the code

```
public class MyProfileModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> userManager;

    
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public MyProfileFormModel FormModel { get; set; }


    public MyProfileModel(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager        = userManager;
    }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        if (User != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var loggedUser          = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            Email                   = loggedUser.Email;
            FormModel               = new MyProfileFormModel( User.FindFirstValue("FullName") );
        }
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            
        }

        return Page();
    }
}
```

```html
@model MyProfileModel

@{
    Layout = "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewData["Title"] = "My Profile";
}

<h2>My Profile</h2>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Email:</label>
    <label class="form-control">@Model.Email</label>
</div>

<form class="row g-3" asp-page="MyProfile">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="inputFullName" class="form-label">Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFullName" placeholder="Please enter your full name" asp-for="FormModel.FullName">
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="FormModel.FullName"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

@Model.Email data is lost when the same page loads in model error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OnPost method, model is error because may be `Page()`. possibly it's re-renders the page and initializes the properties again as well as your Email property.
when your full name is empty, it's indicate ModelState is not valid. return `Page()` does not trigger the OnGet method might be you thought that it does. That case it's load current page without performing any additional method logic.

For resolve, you can update code like below.

```
public class MyProfileModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> userManager;

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public MyProfileFormModel FormModel { get; set; }

    public MyProfileModel(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        if (User != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var loggedUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            Email = loggedUser.Email;
            FormModel = new MyProfileFormModel(User.FindFirstValue("FullName"));

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Email", Email); 
        }

        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            Email = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Email"); 
        }

        return Page();
    }
}
```

And don't forget to include `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;`for access the `Session`. Hope it will resove your issue.

Comment: Thanks for this @PritomSarkar. Fixed my issue. I was wondering whether there was another way or I was doing something wrong.